# Thingsboard: is it possible to simulate the loading of a json file with MQTT and/or Mosquitto?

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

I have several json files with 10 statistical markers.
I would like to know if there is a way to load these files in real-time without a device or a sensor.

Comment: You probably need to add some more detail here, but there should be nothing stoping you writing a script/program to read the file and publish the right MQTT messages at what ever rate you want.

Comment: One question is that I need the program to publish MQTT messages with json. The second is that I don't know how import messages in Thingsboard.

Comment: Please explain what does it mean 'load into ThingsBoard' ? In other words, how you plan to use those files inside the ThingsBoard?